# What is efficient way to ensure bash script variable is valid permission bits?

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions, chmod

I'm inexperienced with `bash` scripts, mostly cobbling things together from google searches. The following simple script creates file foo and changes its permission bits to whatever the script's `$1` is. Can an experienced `bash` scripter please advise  what would be a proper and/or efficient way to ensure that `$1` is valid permission bits, i.e. a valid `arg1` to `chmod`?

```
#!/bin/sh
#mkfoo.sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  return
fi

perm=$1

touch ./foo
chmod "${perm}" ./foo
```

As part of my inexperience, I'm unclear when/why variables are strings or integers. A string-validation approach feels infeasible because of the number of values the permission bits could be. What comes to mind is that I'd want to validate *whether* `$1` is an integer, and if so, that it's between 0 and 777. But I'm unclear if that's a sufficient/efficient validation: I've got a rudimentary understanding of linux file permissions, and I'm led to believe there are lots of subtleties. Grateful for help.

Comment: why do you need to validate? What do you plan to do in case of an error?

Comment: This is not easy, because `chmod` allows complicated symbolic permission specifications, like `u+r,o-w`. Why don't you just check whether `chmod` is successful?

Comment: Permission bits are `4 2 1` for read, write, and execute; ordered as _user_, _group_, and _other_, so 198 is between 0 and 777 but is not valid, so that's not sufficient validation. I was about to also mention the symbolic representation, but Barmar already did.

Comment: If you only want to allow numeric permissions, you could just check if it matches the pattern `[0-7][0-7][0-7]`

Comment: @jeremysprofile I'd want to dot do anything; also my concern is about passing bad arguments to `chmod`: will it output error messages (undesirable) or have some other negative impact to file foo?

Comment: @Barmar - do you mean validate the argument using a regex (I'm not sure how to implement the validation you suggested)?

Comment: If this is "create and set permission" you'd better check if the file (or directory) already exists. `touch` will update the date on an already existing file, then `chmod` will set the permissions. You _could_ create the file only if it doesn't already exist, chmod it, and if the chmod fails then delete it -- but that's very dangerous if the file already exists.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't care about my reputation ding, but why was this question downvoted? I wish there was a way to know why. </rant>

Comment: @StoneThrow, at a guess (wasn't me): this question is fairly simple, and validating an integer in bash (since you appear not to care about other permissions options of `chmod`) has been asked many times and should be findable via google

Comment: It didn't cross my mind that `chmod` took non-numeric input; glad I came here to ask. For that reason, I think I'll pick @jeremysprofile 's answer, since I didn't intentionally only want to allow numeric input - it's just the alternatives hadn't crossed my mind. Thanks to all (except the downvoter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, your goal is to give up on the chmod if the permissions specified are invalid.

```
chmod "$1" ./foo 2>/dev/null
```

`2` is the file descriptor for stderr. Redirecting to `/dev/null` will let it fail silently. `chmod`, as stated in the comments, does its own validation on if the permissions are acceptable.

Comment: Of course, this will still leave the file that was created, just without the permissions you asked for.

Comment: @StephenP, yes. I assumed that was the goal. appending `|| rm ./foo` easily solves that problem, however.

Comment: It's an acceptable outcome in my case for a file to be created with the default permission if `$1` is bad input.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to allow numeric permissions, you can check them with a pattern check:

```
case "$perms" in 
    [0-7][0-7][0-7]) 
        touch ./foo
        chmod "${perm}" ./foo
        ;;
    *) 
        echo "Invalid permissions $perms"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Valid permissions are actually 4 digits long, counting the set-uid, set-guid, and sticky bits

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that he's only interested in the basic perms.

Answer (score 1):

This script will accept any valid permissions that `chmod` allows.
It will create the file (if it doesn't already exist) and attempt to set the permissions. If setting the permissions fails the file is removed.
It requires exactly two arguments; the filename to create and the permissions to set.

This allows you to use symbolic or 4-digit permissions, such as `create foo u+x,g+rwx` (assuming the script is named "create") or `create foo 2640`

This is pretty simple, as an example. I often include a `usage()` function which I would call in place of the first `echo`. You could also include default permissions if the seconds argument was omitted.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "output a usage message, don't just return"
    exit
fi

if [ -e "${1}" ]
then
    echo "${1} already exists"
    exit
fi

touch ./"${1}"

if chmod "${2}" "${1}" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "${1} created with permissions ${2}"
else
    rm "${1}"
    echo "${1} not created: invalid permissions: ${2}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, chmod does its own validation so it'd probably be best to just use that, but if you absolutely want to do this in a way similar to the code you provided you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid input"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ $1 =~ [0-7][0-7][0-7] ]]
then
    echo "Invalid input"
    exit 1
else
    perm=$1
fi

touch ./foo
chmod "${perm}" ./foo
```

This will ensure that each digit is valid.

Comment: That's a valid point you bring up, that chmod will do its own validation. I was just concerned about error messages it might throw out - but this is addressed by @jeremysprofile 's suggestion to redirect `stderr`'s output to `/dev/null`